# Unable to link CSS file in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to link my CSS and HTML. My CSS file is in static folder where as index file in templates folder.

code : Header of index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>BMI App</title>
    <link   href="C:\Users\Shweta\MFRTPPython\static\main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Even after providing it's proper path, I am unable to link them.

Comment: You need to look into `relative` and `absolute` path for this.

Comment: You have to use this way  `<link rel="Stylesheet" href="./static/main.css" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! But it is still not working. I am using VS Code for the development. Does that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below way, it is almost similar of what you've used but you need to know how to locate the `external` file.

If you have a file in a location which is outside from the project folder then you can try something like this:

```
<link href="file:///C:\Users\Shweta\MFRTPPython\static\main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

**OR**

if you know about how `absolute` and `relative` path works then below is what you can try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./yourDirectory/yourFile.css"
```

My advice to you is to create a `folder` in your project and add that `stylesheet` file into that folder and refer that path in the html.

Kindly go through this [path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) for better understanding of `absolute` and `relative`path.

Comment: That was helpful ! May be there is something I am still missing as it is not working out.

Comment: Sad to hear that, would you need help now? we can connect and try to get this fixed.

Comment: That would be great. Please let me know how to connect in your free time.

Comment: what I want you to do is, copy the image and create a folder into the project folder as `images` and then dump that image, so that image must be seen in you project. Once that is done you can use relative path, you will get articles to refer that image and use it in your project. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I was able connect my CSS to HTML. I was missing out on relative path concept.

Comment: Glad I was able to help you out, would you mind voting the answer if you think if it is worth voting?